# drawCircle method not working properly (Android)

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

I am trying to design board for game which will have 5*6 grid of circles. I will use these circles to show bitmap image(.png) in them. **The problem I am facing is that. When I draw grid of circles it does not spread properly on screen.** I am using android device which have this (480 x 854 pixels, 5.0 inches (~196 ppi pixel density)) Screen Size. I tried different combinations to draw circles but I failed.

Here is the code.

```
          package com.example.rectangle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new board(this));
    }
    public class board extends View
    {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        Paint blue=new Paint();
        // Paint green=new Paint();
        int rows=5;
        int cols=6;
        Bitmap [][] dot=new Bitmap[rows][cols];
        Canvas g=new Canvas();
        public board(Context context) {
            super(context);
            p.setARGB(255, 255, 102,0);
            blue.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
            // green.setARGB(0, 0, 06, 0);

        }
        @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawPaint(p);
            for(int y=0; y<cols; y++)
            {
                for(int x=0; x<rows; x++)
                {
                    Bitmap grid= Bitmap.createBitmap(100,100, Config.RGB_565 );

                    dot[x][y]=grid;
                    g.setBitmap(dot[x][y]);
                    //canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 20, blue);
                    //g.drawCircle(50, 50, 20, blue);


                }
            }
            for(int y=0; y<cols; y++)
            {
                for(int x=0; x<rows; x++)
                {
                    //canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 20, blue);
                    //canvas.drawCircle(50, (x + 1) * 2 * 50, (y + 1) * 2 * 50, blue);
                    canvas.drawCircle(85*x, 110*y, 20, blue);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(dot[x][y], x*100, y*100,null);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

- The problem is in this line: canvas.drawCircle(90*x, 110*y, 20,
  blue);
- And Screen Size is: (480 x 854 pixels, 5.0 inches (~196 ppi pixel
  density)

Comment: what problem do you have wuth drawCircle? post an image presenring wrong behaviour etc

Comment: It requires at least 10 to 15 reputations for posting an image.

Comment: When I run code with different combination of values it display half circles on 100*x and 100*y. Some times it shows 4*5 rows instead of 5*6 it hides its circles on left side of screen

Comment: what about postimage.org or like?

Comment: why do you ceate a Bitmap in onDraw? dont you see lint warnings? what is that Bitmap for ?

Comment: Here is the link.it shows my device screen.  http://postimg.org/image/hqoqyuq2b/

Comment: Lint does not show any warning.

Comment: Yes a bitmap in onDraw  : Bitmap grid= Bitmap.createBitmap(100,100, Config.RGB_565 );

Comment: what is that Bitmap for ???

Comment: I am editing this question and sharing file so that you can understand the problem.

Comment: @pskink Please check the edited question, and suggest replacement for Bitmap if you feel it is not appropriate.

Comment: @pskink I am new to android so I don't know too much about android. createBitmap was suggested in a tutorial and I simply used it.

Comment: where was it suggested?

Comment: In a youtube tutorial. I don't remember its URL now.

Comment: @UmarFarooq, I know what your problems are, and I want to post the code to show you what to change, but I can't quite tell what you're trying to do with the Bitmaps. If you could explain what your goal is, I think I can help you.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you for consideration. I was trying to make such game (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pixelcrater.SmartDots) and for that I have to make board which consists of grid of circles containing .png image in them as you can see from the game (Link Mentioned above). Initially I have to make board. In above mentioned edited code I have shown circles on screen but the problem is those circles are not spread-ed properly.

Comment: Ok, well, I'm not sure how you wish to implement the Bitmaps, but I'll post the fix for the spacing problem with the circles.

Comment: @MikeM. if you think Bitmap is not appropriate for this purpose, you can change to what you think is good,

Comment: And it will be favor if you solve circle spacing problem.

Comment: I want to display such screen. Which display grid of circles and allow players to tap between two circles either horizontally or vertically but not vertically. and on tap it should show a line between those two circles. http://postimg.org/image/dussext0v/

Comment: And eventually it should work like this http://postimg.org/image/vh0bs14dv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you're getting the `x`/`y` (horizontal/vertical) and `rows`/`cols` mixed up. `x` (horizontal) should be determined by `cols`, and `y` (vertical) by `rows`. The code below is a very minimal example, as, I'm sure, you will need to make adjustments to the graphical layout as your project progresses. Please note that the grid's vertical centering might be a little off, depending on whether your app has a title bar, and whether it is full-screen.

```
public class board extends View
{
    Paint pBack = new Paint();
    Paint pDot = new Paint();

    int cols = 5;
    int rows = 6;

    public board(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        pBack.setARGB(255, 255, 102, 0);
        pDot.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPaint(pBack);

        float xStep = canvas.getWidth() / (cols + 1);
        float yStep = canvas.getHeight() / (rows + 1);

        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
            {
                canvas.drawCircle((x + 1) * xStep, (y + 1) * yStep, 20, pDot);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Bitmaps are fine for what you're intending. I just meant that I didn't know if they were generated programmatically, loaded from resources, etc.

Comment: Now I want to display an image from my resource folder. In these circles. Like I want to display a black dot in these circles. What modification you recommend?

Comment: No, I want to show image of any color which is stored in res folder's drawable folder.

Comment: Then you would use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` and `Canvas.drawBitmap()`.

Comment: Sir, Please check your mail.

Answer (score 0):

im using this code to draw a piechart and its working with me: hope it will help:

```
public class AChartEnginePieChartActivity extends Activity { 

private static int[] COLORS = new int[] { Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE,Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN };

private static double[] VALUES = new double[] { 10, 11, 12, 13 };

private static String[] NAME_LIST = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

private CategorySeries mSeries = new CategorySeries("");

private DefaultRenderer mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();

private GraphicalView mChartView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 50, 50, 50));
mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
mRenderer.setStartAngle(90);

for (int i = 0; i < VALUES.length; i++) {
mSeries.add(NAME_LIST[i] + " " + VALUES[i], VALUES[i]);
SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
renderer.setColor(COLORS[(mSeries.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS.length]);
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
}

if (mChartView != null) {
mChartView.repaint();
}

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
if (mChartView == null) {
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer);
mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();

if (seriesSelection == null) {
Toast.makeText(AChartEnginePieChartActivity.this,"No chart element was clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
Toast.makeText(AChartEnginePieChartActivity.this,"Chart element data point index "+ (seriesSelection.getPointIndex()+1) + " was clicked" + " point value="+ seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
});

mChartView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
if (seriesSelection == null) {
Toast.makeText(AChartEnginePieChartActivity.this,"No chart element was long pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
return false; 
} else {
Toast.makeText(AChartEnginePieChartActivity.this,"Chart element data point index "+ seriesSelection.getPointIndex()+ " was long pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
return true;       
}
}
});
layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
}
else {
mChartView.repaint();
}
}
}
```

you may replace the name list with background img resourse.

Comment: I want to display grid of circles.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I think it will not fulfill my requirements. Which part of this code I should use?

Comment: ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer); to draw ,
mSeries is the sections ,
render is proprieties.